# Editing a tableview in a tabbed application

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tabbed view application which uses a tab controller as the root view controller. One of the views I have is a tableview with I want to be able to edit by clicking on an add/edit button that will make all the cells editable as well as allowing to add a cell.

In the table view I have added a navigation bar and have tried to use the following code to create a button on the bar that when pressed will make all the cells editable:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(toggleEdit:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;          

}


-(IBAction)toggleEdit:(id)sender {

    [self.mTableView setEditing:!self.mTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.mTableView.editing) 
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Delete"];

}
```

The code doesn't work, it doesn't produce a button on the navigation bar. I have read that I should use a navigation controller but if I wish to have this one page (in my tabbed view app) use a navigation controller how do I get the tab bar to point to the nav controller as a selection option?

----Update-----
Ok Ive made a nib file that contains the root view controller (a tab bar controller). The tab bar controller contains 2 view controllers and a navigation controller with a view controller in it. I link the View controller in the Navigation controller to a View that contains a tableview. When I run the program and try to click on the tab for the tableview I get the following error:

2012-04-29 17:23:28.116 ash[6778:f803] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68bb8d0
2012-04-29 17:23:28.117 ash[6778:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68bb8d0'

My view controller that contains the tableview is a UIViewController that implements

In its m file it contains the following methods:

```
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [self.portfolioArray count];
     }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";
      static BOOL nibsregistered = NO;
      if (!nibsregistered) {
      UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ASHInstrumentCell" bundle:nil];
      [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
      nibsregistered = YES;
     }

     ASHInstrumentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                         SimpleTableIdentifier];


      NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

     cell.type.text = [portfolioArray objectAtIndex:row];

     return cell;
    }


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table Delegate Methods


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *rowValue = [portfolioArray objectAtIndex:row];

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                     @"You selected %@", rowValue];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                         initWithTitle:@"Row Selected!"
                         message:message
                         delegate:nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes I Did"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:                (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]
        [self.portfolioArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic] ;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two points:  First of all, a `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so you could create an instance of UINavigationController whose rootViewController is your tableViewController, and have the TabBarController manage the nav controller as one of its tabs.

Also note that the UIViewController class already has a `editButtonItem` property that you should use instead of creating your own button:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Comment: Ive updated my original question to indicate what Ive tried so far, I'm still having problems though

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had created a nib file for my tab view controller and to this I added to view controllers and a Navigation controller (which itself contained a tableview controller).

One of the things I wasn't doing was allocating the correct class type to the view controllers in my tabs. If I have created a custom view controller class firstviewcontroller which had IBOutlets and I didn't specify the view controller in my tab controller nib to be of class firstviewcontroller I would get that weird key value error.

The second problem I had was that the tab view controller wouldn't autorotate even though all the view I wanted to show allowed for autorotation using the following code:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
     return YES;
    }
```

The reason for this again was that I hadn't specified the class of each of the view controllers (in my tabbedviewcontroller nib file) to be of my custom made classes that I wished them to show.

Once I specified their class type everything fell into place.